# Spring cloud zuul proxy mapping with Spring Data Rest API

Tags: spring-data-rest, spring-cloud, netflix-zuul

Following the articles on [Angular JS and Spring Security](http://spring.io/blog/2015/02/03/sso-with-oauth2-angular-js-and-spring-security-part-v) I have an API based on Spring Data Rest and Client app on angularjs. API is hosted on context "some-api" while client app is hosted on root context. Zuul proxy configuration for client app is like below. While everything is dandy, the proxy configuration between client app and API is not working as expected. The response from client /api contains "some-api" sub context which breaks API calls.

**Zuul Config:**

```
server.port: 9900
zuul:
  routes:
    api:
      path: /api/**
      url: http://localhost:9988/some-api
```

**API App:**

> http://localhost:9988/some-api/

```
{
    "_links": {
        "resources": {
            "href": "http://localhost:9988/some-api/resources{?page,size,sort}",
            "templated": true
        },
        "profile": {
            "href": "http://localhost:9988/some-api/alps"
        }
    }
}
```

**Client App:**

> http://localhost:9900/api/

```
{
  "_links" : {
    "resources" : {
      "href" : "http://localhost:9900/api/some-api/resources{?page,size,sort}",
      "templated" : true
    },
    "profile" : {
      "href" : "http://localhost:9900/api/some-api/alps"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I'm confused by the ports in your question.  I see 9000, 9988 and 9900.  Which app is zuul used in?

Comment: sorry a typo, corrected!

Comment: the `some-api` comes from Spring Data, if I'm not mistaken.  Maybe try setting `url` without `/some-api`?

Comment: Yes `some-api` is the context on which API is hosted using Spring Data Rest. If I host this API on root context (/) everything works fine. However the API would have a context (or sub context), think of versioning of API like ..../v1/. So context (or sub-context) for API is needed in my case.

Comment: Why can't you put the prefix in the proxy? If it all works when the backend runs in the root context, I don't see what the problem is.

Comment: Not sure I understand "put the prefix in the proxy" means? Do you means zuul proxy? 1. My API app would have multiple versions of API hence I need a context. 2. Also further in the future we are thinking of hosting API broswer app within the the API app which means we would like to separate api under `/api` sub context and API browser app under root.

Comment: This issue was treated on https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATAREST-620